# How to enable table resizer in CKEditor 4?

Tags: ckeditor

On their [demo page](http://ckeditor.com/demo#table-resizer) they show how you can click and drag table borders to resize columns. How do I enable this feature?

I can't find it in the docs, can't find a plugin for it, can't find any references to "resize" in the source code, and the source code for the configuration isn't shown on the demo page itself (View source is mostly unreadable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table Resize plugin isn't available by default in any of three available presets (basic, std, full).

You have to  add [Table Resize](http://ckeditor.com/addon/tableresize) plugin to [your own build](http://ckeditor.com/builder) of CKEditor. It will be enabled by default, so you don't have to use `extraPlugins` config setting.

You can find more information here: [Plugins - CKEditor 4 documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_plugins).

Comment: Yes, I know about the `extraPlugins` setting but I didn't see a folder for it in the full package / plugins. I only see "table" and "tabletools". I'll try adding "tableresize" in a sec; thanks.

Comment: Oups - my mistake - there's no tableresize even in full build. You've got to build your own version. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Needed to add it to `extraPlugins`, but it works now. (Didn't do a custom build -- it's too late for that!)